# How can I keep the cursor focus on terminal when start a GUI binary file in terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript

There has a GUI program binary file. I start in terminal like `path/to/binaryfile some args`. then it will generate a GUI window in frontend and my cursor in this window. I want to keep the cursor always in terminal. how can I do this? start it `path/to/binary args` then the cursor also in terminal not jump to this GUI window.my env is macos

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/123448/os-x-how-to-have-starting-applications-optionally-not-take-the-focus

Comment: AFAIK, macOS requires the front most app to have cursor focus. X Windows was different and very flexible, but not here. Write a script/alias to launch the GUI and then reactivate Terminal.